# Preventing direct access to link while tipping the url

Tags: php

Could you give me please a hint regarding url restrictions.

My filestructure looks more ore less like this:

```
root/
-> index.php
-> user.php
/housekeeping/
-> searchuser.php (search user in DB via sql)
-> deleteuser.php (delete user in DB via sql)
```

- index.php is including searchuser.php
- user.php is including deleteuser.php

How can I now prevent when a user is directly tipping like:
www.host.com/housekeeping/searchuser.php
that he execute this scrypt?

But for the "system" it should be allowed of course to include and execute
it from index.php

thx a lot

Comment: Put it above the web root

Comment: I know you can tip cows, but how do you tip an URL …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of index.php:

```
define('IS_INCLUDED', true);
```

At the beginning of searchuser.php:

```
if(!defined('IS_INCLUDED')) { exit(); }
```